# Why often project name start with com phase?

Tags: maven, project, setup-project

I see several project that its naming start with `com` such as `com.company_name.project_name`.
For sample at [tutorial of maven at apache site](http://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html) for sample project says: `mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=com.mycompany.app -DartifactId=my-app -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart -Dinteractiv`

This issue maybe simple for more people but is ambiguous for me.

My question is: What often project naming start with `com`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because by conventions `com` is for commercial (http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/.com ) and in Java, and in Maven too, we tends to use the reverse host name (eg: app.mycompany.com -> com.mycompany.app).

Apache or Codehaus would use org.

Comment: Your response is good. What use when my application is not commercial?

Comment: You are free to use anything or nothing. Like @rotifan says in his answers, it is a convention. I use 'eu' for my own project since I live in eu, but net or org would be fine too. And if you don't share your code and really don't like it, you can omit it. As for maven, http://search.maven.org/#browse : there are already project *without* com/etc.

Answer (score 1):

That comes from the Java package naming convention.  See the Java [Naming a package](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/namingpkgs.html) page  for more details.  The relevant part that explains `com.companyname` packages states "Companies use their reversed Internet domain name to begin their package names—for example, com.example.mypackage for a package named mypackage created by a programmer at example.com."

Comment: If our company hasn't domain name?

Comment: In that case you can make something up but follow the spirit of the convention.  The point of the naming system is to prevent naming two classes the same thing, and if you've got a registered domain name then that's known to be unique.  You'll be fine as long as you pick a package name for your code that doesn't match anything used by any third parties you use.  If you share your code with others (e.g. sharing your jar or publishing with Maven) then you'll need to be thoughtful with your package name to pick something that others are unlikely to also use.